Creating event trigger failed - trigger in db but not in Hasura
Background:
I was using multiple tabs to create event triggers, and my second event trigger failed to create because the metadata was stale.
Issue:
When I attempted to re-create it, I saw the error: "Creating event trigger failed" saying that the trigger already exists.

I tried reloading the metadata, but the trigger does not show up in the event triggers section:

Also, metadata export from Hasura does not show the trigger.
BUT, when I use pgadmin to inspect the trigger functions in the hdb_catalog schema, I do see the trigger:

Question:
Is there a way to fix Hasura so the admin UI is consistent with the DB? Or to clean up the DB state?
Hasura version: v2.25.1-ce
